# Android Activity order

Tags: android, android-activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="muazam.multiplication.one"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
           <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".multiplication">
            <intent-filter android:priority="1">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".splash">
            <intent-filter android:priority="3">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CLEARSCREEN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

            <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".Menu">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2">
                <action android:name="muazam.multiplication.one.Play" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>
</manifest>
```

I want it to start with the .splash class first, and then .Menu class.
As you see I have put android:priority on them, but it seem to do nothing.

Anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: If I get your problem, you want to show a "splash"-activity before you show the first activity?

Comment: Correct Joakim, CommonsWare helped me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want it to start with the .splash class first

That has no meaning in Android.

If you meant to say "I want the .splash class to be what launches when the icon in the home screen launcher is clicked", then you need to get rid of the `.splash` class' current `<intent-filter>` (which is simply wrong) and move your `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` from the `.multiplication` class to the .`splash` class.

While you are at it, please get rid of the `android:priority` attributes (which are not used here) and your `Play`/`DEFAULT` `<intent-filter>` (which you really should not need, unless you plan on third-party apps starting up that activity directly).

> and then .Menu class

You do this in Java code with `startActivity()`.

> As you see I have put android:priority on them, but it seem to do nothing.

Of course. There is no `android:priority` attribute for the `<activity>` element, as you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Comment: I see that makes sense, I've been taught wrong. I really appirciate your comment, it helped me and it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Activities aren't run automatically like a 'slide show' (although you could write your own code that way if you really wanted to).

The `android:priority` attribute is used for an entirely different purpose (from the docs for `<intent-filter>`...

> It provides information about how able
>   an activity is to respond to an intent
>   that matches the filter, relative to
>   other activities that could also
>   respond to the intent. When an intent
>   could be handled by multiple
>   activities with different priorities,
>   Android will consider only those with
>   higher priority values as potential
>   targets for the intent.

In other word, if you have two activities each having an intent filter with the same action and category, then any Intent sent (from a 3rd party app) with those action/category details, will be passed first to the Activity whose intent filter has the highest priority.

This has nothing to do with how an app (and its activities) behave internally at runtime.

Comment: Aha! Thanks, I keep that in mind when I get into 3rd partying. Thanks for the explanation. I was totally driving in the wrong way.